# Wind tunnel corrections for a finite wing

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

**Background**
I have hydrofoil measurements taken from a water channel of an semispan elliptical planform wing. The wing profile is a NACA0012. I'm trying to correct the force measurements to take into consideration the tunnel walls etc. My assumption is the difference between inviscid theory and the corrected tunnel results should be the effect of viscosity, but, the difference seems quite large.

**Geometry**

- chord $c$ is 150mm
- semi-span $b$ is 176.7mm
- full-span aspect ratio $AR$ is 3
- tunnel is 600mm square $H = 600$
- profile is NACA0012, and the planform is elliptical

**Inviscid results**
A two-dimensional wing would give $C_L = \alpha \cdot a$. For a NACA0012, $a$, or $\frac{dC_l}{d\alpha}$, is 0.119 (per degree). So we can easily get that result (plotted as black dots).

To correct for the fact that it is a finite wing ($fw$), I used this correction from Helmbold 1942:

$a_{fw} = \frac{a}{\sqrt{1+(\frac{a}{\pi AR})^2} + \frac{a}{\pi AR}}$

which gives $a_{fw} = 0.061$, or 51%. This result is plotted in the black line.

**Experimental results**
The (uncorrected) data from the load cell is given by the blue points. To this, I apply two corrections. Firstly since there is somen solid blockage, the velocity on the foil is larger than we measure, so the lift coefficient is overestimated. Given the frontal area, $A$, and putting that in this correction, yields:

$\epsilon = (1+\frac{t}{c})\frac{\pi}{6}\frac{A}{H^2}$

$C_{L,sb} = \frac{C_L}{(1+\epsilon)^2}$

Which returns the red data points (shifting the experimental results down). There is also a correction necessary because of the wake blockage. To correct for this, I find the $\delta$ value from Galuert (which I actually pulled from Barlow's wind tunnel book, pg 389), gives $\delta = 0.14$. This gives a change in angle-of-attack of:

$\Delta\alpha = \delta\frac{2S}{H^2}C_{L,sb}\cdot 57.3$

A plot of $C_{L,sb}$ against $\alpha + \Delta\alpha$ gives the yellow points (shifting the data to the right).

**Questions**

1. I am doing something obviously wrong, like making one of my corrections act in the wrong direction?
2. Should I even expect that the data sets (yellow and black line) should become close?

[image: Results]

Comment: Who is supervising this project, and why don't you ask that person these questions?

Comment: The inviscid thin airfoil theory lift slope is $2\pi \ \text{rad}^{-1}$ or  $0.1097 \ \text{deg}^{-1}$, not the $0.119 \ \text{deg}^{-1}$ as you have stated above. That will make a slight difference. The number you mentioned is about 9% higher than the theoretical maximum of an infinitely thin airfoil section.

Comment: @James Did that correct your analytical/experimental comparison?

Comment: No, it wasn't enough to bring it back to the yellow line.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this [AGARD Report](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/657092.pdf) helpful. I suspect that correcting for the presence of the solid boundary above and below the wing using the method of images will help but, yes, due to the presence of viscous effects (i.e., a boundary layer) on your airfoil you cannot expect the data to match the $2\pi$ slope corrected with only the downwash effects.